# How to assemble table (HTML + PHP) using current week number and fifteen coming weeks

Tags: php

How to assemble table (HTML + PHP) using current week number and fifteen coming weeks `(29 + 15 = 44 and 37 + 15 = 52)`
Where data is obtained from a query that may have result as horizontal or Vertical:

[image]

Another difficulty would be the exchange of year, as shown on line 9

```
Year: 2015
Week: 42 + 15 = 57 (Max Week 52) >> 57-52 = 5
```

Then we will have in

```
 2015 42 ... 43 ... 44 ... 45 ... 46 ... 47 ... 48 ... 49 ... 50 ... 51 ... 52 ....
```

and in

```
 2016 1 ... 2 .... 3 .... 4 .... 5 ...
```

example :

[image]

Comment: i totally dont get your question, but i think using Group By clause in your query might help, 
And please try to make logic , and be more specific in your questions

Comment: I need to mount a table which always shows the data of the current week and the next 15 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own doubt, I appreciate everyone's attention.

Code used to resolve my doubt.

```
      $date = new DateTime('first monday this week');
  $weeks = 15;
  $query_week = array();

  while($weeks > 0) {
      $endDate = clone $date;
      $endDate->modify('+6 day');

      $query_week[] = sprintf("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE table1.fieldA BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' AND table1.fieldB = table2.fieldA) as week_%s", $date->format('Y-m-d'), $endDate->format('Y-m-d'), $date->format('W'));
      $date->modify('+7 day');

      $weeks--;
  }

  $query = sprintf('
      SELECT table2.fieldA,
             table2.fieldB,
             table2.fieldC,
             %s
        FROM table2', implode(', ' . PHP_EOL, $query_week));

  echo '<pre>';
  echo $query;
```